# Couldn't open intellij as sudo user It shows error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment

Tags: permissions, sudo, xdg

When I try to open intellij as sudo user,

Command : `sudo intellij-idea-community`

Result:
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
error: **XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.**

When I run `echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` , it returns data like `/run/user/1001` .
Why it shows not set in the env during intellij open via sudo user ? Kindly help me on this. Thanks

Comment: The simple answer is "don't". Don't run graphical applications under sudo. What's the goal here? Why are you running a desktop application as root?